# PayPal callback does not trigger after login to the PayPal account

Tags: android, paypal

I'm stuck with the next issue.

I integrated PayPal sdk into my android app.

`implementation 'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.6.1'`

My app has an underscore in the package name so I have to use ‘App links’. I tested it in the test-app, all works fine like on the first screenschoot.

But in the main app when I successfully log in to a paypal account and redirect back to the app, the callback does not trigger.

I also figured out if I press on close button, callback yes triggers.
Also when I returns to the app I receive Intent like this:

`app.mobile.main.app.name://paypalpay?code=C21AALAqib-oCkJXmgsoDPPbpAiYza7KJgVoA_01gzzYtawIsgofw0PmCpr186xkz1OY6tSQ...`.

Please write if you have any suggestions.
Thanks and have a nice day.

Here snippets of Manifest file and PayPalFragment.

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="app.mobile.main_app.name">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
       android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

   <application
       android:name=".MyApplication"
       android:allowBackup="false"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:largeHeap="true"
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
     

       <activity
           android:name=".Ux.Activities.MainActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
           android:excludeFromRecents="true"
           android:exported="true"
           android:launchMode="singleTop"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">

           <intent-filter >
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />   
           </intent-filter>

           <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

               <data
                   android:host="paypalpay"
                   android:scheme="app.mobile.main.app.name" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

PayPalFragment.kt

```
class PayPalFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        PayPalCheckout.registerCallbacks(
            onApprove = OnApprove { approval ->
                approval.orderActions.capture { captureOrderResult ->
                    Log.i("tester", "OnApprove called.")
                }
            },
            onCancel = OnCancel {
                Log.i("tester", "OnCancel called.")
            },
            onError = OnError { errorInfo ->
                Log.i("tester", "onError called.")
            },
            onShippingChange = OnShippingChange { shippingChangeData, shippingChangeActions ->
                Log.i("tester", "onShippingChange called.")
            }
        )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pay_pal, container, false)

        val payPalButton = fragView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.paypal_button)
        payPalButton.setOnClickListener {
            PayPalCheckout.startCheckout(
                CreateOrder { createOrderActions ->
                    val order = Order(
                        intent = OrderIntent.CAPTURE,
                        appContext = AppContext(
                            userAction = UserAction.PAY_NOW
                        ),
                        purchaseUnitList = listOf(
                            PurchaseUnit(
                                amount = Amount(
                                    currencyCode = CurrencyCode.USD,
                                    value = "10.00"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    createOrderActions.create(order)
                }
            )
        }
        return fragView
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add logging in onApprove before the capture, since in that code it's possible the capture failed

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thanks you, I'll pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solution is to add default PayPal activity to AndroidManifest.xml

You just copy the code below and change `YOUR-CUSTOM-SCHEME` to what you declared in ReturnUrl in the PayPal developer account.

No need to create this activity, it comes with the PayPal SDK.

It will redirect you back into your app and trigger a PayPal payment sheet.

After the user has completed or canceled the payment, the corresponding callback will be called.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paypal.openid.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:theme="@style/PYPLAppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="paypalpay"
            android:scheme="YOUR-CUSTOM-SCHEME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: But i find it in the manifest of the paypal sdk!

Comment: @moumenShobakey If you use App Links, you need to redeclare it in app manifest

Comment: I have a problem that it requests my permission after logging in paypal, to go back my application but it keeps loading !! i tried your approach but no progress, do you have any idea what can be wrong,

Comment: @moumenShobakey  Probably something is not configured correctly. It must be set up on the PayPal website and in the app and have the same configuration. Paypal also has a sandbox and production, you may not be using the one you need. Contact me on linkedin and I'll be happy to help